# Python Pandas Drop reordering my dataframe when using drop

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with a dataframe where I have to take two columns (quant and sales) add them and then drop them, then capitalize the first letters of my column names. the problem is when I use drop it saves it to another dataframe. From the documentation the problem is from the

> inplace=false

```
import pandas as pd

pie_info_original = pd.DataFrame(
    [("classic", "apple"), ("tangy", "orange"), ("creamy", "banana"),
     ("sour", "raspberry")], 
    columns = ["flavor", "fruit"])
pie_info_original.loc[:,'quant'] = [5,1,8,3]
pie_info_original.loc[:,'sales'] = [2,1,2,3]
pie_info = pie_info_original.drop(['quant', 'sales'], axis=1)
pie_info.rename(index=str, columns={"fruit": "Fruit", "flavor" : "Flavor"})
print(pie_info)
```

My data went from this

```
|  |fruit|flavor |quant|sales|
*****************************
| 0|apple|classic|5    | 2   |
| 1|orange|tangy|1    | 1   |
| 2|banana|creamy|8    | 3   |
| 3|raspberry|sour|3    | 3   |
```

To this

```
|  flavor | fruit 
*****************
| 0|classic|apple|
| 1|tangy|orange |
| 2|creamy|banana|
| 3|sour|raspberry|
```

How would I be able to rearrange my columns so they display in the correct order. I tried setting the inplace to true but that prevents a new dataframe from being created.

**I want fruit to come before flavor

Comment: In which order do you want your columns

Comment: I want fruit and flavor swapped, so it starts with fruit then flavor

Comment: BDW just noticed when i print the dataframe you have provided, flavor comes before fruit, can you check?

Comment: That was the output i was getting

Comment: @anky_91 in earlier version of python 3 dict order was (kinda) random.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than rename you could use the [`str.title`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.title.html) method:

```
In [11]: pie_info.columns.str.title()
Out[11]: Index(['Fruit', 'Flavor'], dtype='object')

In [12]: pie_info.columns = df.columns.str.title()
```

This won't reorder the columns.

Comment: @anky_91 yeah, the re-order is due to not using python 3.7+ ? (after that it's guaranteed insertion order, right?)

Comment: I didnot know this @Andy, yes i am using 3.6.5 version , new learning for me. :) Hopefully for the OP too.

Comment: I'll keep that function in mind as another way of renaming, but still doesn't solve the issue of how i would reorder my columns.

Comment: @onbu with this you don't need to reorder the columns. Use instead of `pie_info.rename`

Answer (score 0):

```
pie_info_original = pd.DataFrame(
    [("classic", "apple"), ("tangy", "orange"), ("creamy", "banana"),
     ("sour", "raspberry")], 
    columns = ["flavor", "fruit"])
pie_info_original.loc[:,'quant'] = [5,1,8,3]
pie_info_original.loc[:,'sales'] = [2,1,2,3]
pie_info = pie_info_original.drop(['quant', 'sales'], axis=1)
pie_info = pie_info.rename(index=str, columns={"fruit": "Fruit", "flavor" : "Flavor"})
pie_info = pie_info[["Fruit", "Flavor"]]
print(pie_info)
```

Output

```
       Fruit   Flavor
0      apple  classic
1     orange    tangy
2     banana   creamy
3  raspberry     sour
```